# Noise in decimal places in R / cutting decimal places

Tags: r

I'm a beginner in R and I've read some related questions but I still have the following problem:
I've got two numbers => 0.6942181641427924709831 and 0.6942181641427929150723. The first one is the result of some calculation, the second one is given/defined. I have to work with those numbers but they need to be equal (exactly)! I've just read about the noise in R ... maybe that's the case here?

So can I cut the numbers just at the e.g. 15th decimal place where they still equal? Rounding doesn't work because it doesn't change the number itself but only what R shows you ...

Thank you guys a lot for your answers!!

Comment: Exact equality at that level of precision is a pipedream, or at least requires special tools. See FAQ 7.31 <http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f> and follow the link to the Goldberg document. Why do the numbers need to be exactly equal to 22 significant figures?

Answer (score 2):

You could do this sort of "almost equal" comparison by checking if the absolute value of their difference is below some threshold.

```
x <- 0.6942181641427924709831
y <- 0.6942181641427929150723
x == y
# [1] FALSE
abs(x-y) < 1e-15
# [1] TRUE
```

The `all.equal` function already has a built-in tolerance that makes this convenient:

```
all.equal(x, y)
# [1] TRUE
```